# NSUserDefaults and boolean - what is going on ? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, lldb

I have this simple code to save and restore boolean from NSUserDefaults.
At the end when I do

```
po [defaults boolForKey:@"dummy"]
```

in the debugger I see nil.

What is going on here ?

```
// Store the data
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setBool:(BOOL)boolValue forKey:@"dummy"];

[defaults synchronize];

BOOL ans = [defaults boolForKey:@"dummy"];
```

Where am I wrong ?

Thanks!

UPDATED: Thanks! Now clear

Comment: have you confirmed control.smartTerrainStarted is not nil?

Comment: @MarkPowell BOOL value can't be nil

Comment: True. haha, ignore that.

Comment: PO is print object `(NSObject * ) NO` is nil

Comment: It can be many issues. One of them can be due to the actual value of boolValue. What is the value of it? Is it NO or YES? Second, -synchronize might not work immediately, because that can take a while to happen. What does happen if you delay the rereading of the default?

Comment: What's the actual question/issue here? You make no attempt to explain what is wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Closed on the assumption that the issue is why a `BOOL` appears as `nil` using `po` in the debugger. If that's not the question then I will reopen.

Answer (score 4):

If you do

```
p [defaults boolForKey:@"dummy"]
```

(which is a proper debugging command for printing primitive types) instead of

```
po [defaults boolForKey:@"dummy"]
```

you will see `NO`

po means `print object` and is suitable for descendants of `NSObject`

p is just `print` and is suitable for primitives like `BOOL` or `int`